# How to get the db table row that has the biggest value in the meta value?

Tags: custom-field

E.g. I have a meta field called `car_number`:

So, normally I would try something like this to get this value:

```
$car_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'car_number');
```

But the porblem is that I need to get the row only where the `car_number` is highest e.g. 45. so I need somehow to get the highest value and do something like this:

```
$post_ID = .. // here I need to get the ID of the post that has the biggest value in the fild car_value

$car_value = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'car_number');
```

how can I get the post_ID of the post that has the highest value (number) in car_value meta field?

Answer (score 3):

The `WP_Query` has a feature called `meta_query`. Using it allows you to either query by value or *numeric* value:

```
$car = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => array( 'cars' ),
    'meta_key'       => 'car_number',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'cache_results'  => true,
) );
$carNr = get_post_meta( $car->ID, 'car_number', true );
// Inspect result
var_dump( $carNr );
```

Now, that we got the right post type, the appropriate meta key and defined that we want to order by its value, we only need to limit the result to a single post and have a descending order. As we now got the post, we can easily grab the meta value.

Another option would be to do a plain query:

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->get_var( 
    "SELECT {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value
     FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
     WHERE 1=1
         AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'car_number'
     ORDER BY ABS( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value ) DESC
     LIMIT 0,1"
);
```

Depending on how you saved your values - often plugins save numbers/digits/integers as strings - you may need to convert your value during the query. In that case replace the order by part with

```
CAST( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value as SIGNED INTEGER )
```

*Note: If you don't have negative integers, you can go with `UNSIGNED`*

or

```
CONVERT( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value, SIGNED INTEGER )
```

Comment: It's not working. If I print_r  $car->ID I get nothing.  Btw. what is `meta_value_num` ?

Comment: I am using this in admin not in frontend. Could that be a problem?

Comment: What does `WHERE 1=1` mean?

Comment: For the future: Please add **every** detail to your question. File an [edit] and state that you need it in the admin UI, where you need it and why you need it. For the other questions, please [consult Google](https://www.google.at/search?q=where+1%3D1&oq=where+1%3D1&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4835j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) and [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: @Derfder Please read the code in detail: As you can see, I assumed that your post type is named `cars`. You'll have to alter the code where your setup defers from this example code.

Comment: but what does `WHERE 1=1` in your 2nd code example mean?

Comment: If you don't want to read that up, then simply leave it away - it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
function end_meta_value( $end = "max", $meta )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT %s( cast( meta_value as UNSIGNED ) ) FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key='%s'",
        $end,
        $meta
    );
    return $wpdb->get_var( $query );
}
```

from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/select-maxmeta-value-from-wp-postmeta-where-meta-key-price-stops-working). For me it worked fine.

Comment: Please always properly escape queries. Else doors are wide open for SQL injections. And if you find a question/answer that fits the purpose please leave a comment or a close vote for a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: Good. I will. Still learning.

Comment: Could you use my values provided in my question? Thank you.

Comment: I am using this in admin. Could taht be a problem?